# Recode factors to number of my choosing

Tags: r, sapply

I like to convert NG to 0, SG=1.25, LG=7.25, MG=26 and HG=40

My actual data that looks exactly like the `t` below is here:
[actual data causing problems](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Aq9RVk-X9bzDhq8MpAfhmX6r00jJCQ)

```
t<-rep(c("NG","SG","LG","MG","HG"),each=5)
colnames(t)<-c("X.1","X1","X2","X4","X8","X12","X24","X48")
```

Why doesn't this work?

```
t[t=="NG"] <- "0"
t[t=="SG"] <- "1.25"
t[t=="LG"] <- "7.25"
t[t=="MG"] <- "26"
```

or this:

```
factor(t, levels=c("NG","SG","LG","MG", "HG"), labels=c("0","1.25","7.25","26","40"))
```

or this:

```
t <- sapply(t,switch,"NG"=0,"SG"=1.25,"LG"=7.25,"MG"=26, "HG"=40)
```

Comment: Seems to work for me. What's the issue?

Comment: It also works for me

Comment: work for me as well

Comment: @thelatemail > factor(t, levels=c("NG","SG","LG","MG", "HG"), labels=c("0","1.25","7.25","26","40"))
 X.1   X1   X2   X4   X8  X12  X24  X48 
<NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> 
Levels: 0 1.25 7.25 26 40
> sapply(t,switch,"NG"=0,"SG"=1.25,"LG"=7.25,"MG"=26, "HG"=40)
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : EXPR must be a length 1 vector

Comment: In my data.frame the NG etc don't have any " " around them... what does that mean? It works fine with the example data above...

Comment: You first do something like `t <- factor(t)` it will take away any `"` from the `NG` etc.

Comment: as.factor(t)
Error in sort.list(y) : 'x' must be atomic for 'sort.list'
Have you called 'sort' on a list?

Comment: Is your `t` a list?

Comment: @MKR not as far as I know. R says it's a data.frame...

Comment: Then also you cannot apply factor on whole data.frame. You can apply `factor` on columns. Hence you have to call as `as.factor(df$colname)`

Comment: I've done that but still gives me the same errors. So strange.

Answer (score 1):

You may want this:

```
t <- rep(c(NG = 0, SG = 1.25, LG = 7.25, MG = 26, HG = 40), each = 5)
t <- factor(t)
levels(t)
# [1] "0"    "1.25" "7.25" "26"   "40"  
labels(t)
# [1] "NG" "NG" "NG" "NG" "NG" "SG" "SG" "SG" "SG" "SG" "LG" "LG" "LG" "LG" "LG"
# [16] "MG" "MG" "MG" "MG" "MG" "HG" "HG" "HG" "HG" "HG"
```

The internal codes for the factor will always be integers, so you can't create a factor with internal codes that are double precision floats.

```
unclass(t)
# NG NG NG NG NG SG SG SG SG SG LG LG LG LG LG MG MG MG MG MG HG HG HG HG HG 
#  1  1  1  1  1  2  2  2  2  2  3  3  3  3  3  4  4  4  4  4  5  5  5  5  5 
# attr(,"levels")
# [1] "0"    "1.25" "7.25" "26"   "40"
```

You can still extract the numerical value using the label for a level:

```
t["SG"]
#   SG
# 1.25
# Levels: 0  1.25  7.25  26  40
```

Comment: > factor(t)
Error in sort.list(y) : 'x' must be atomic for 'sort.list'
Have you called 'sort' on a list? But It's a data.frame... I'm really confused by this.

Comment: data.frames are a particular type of list